# Display element based on route - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm having awful trouble trying to make the navbar set `display:none` based on the route I want. I did succeed in subscribing to the route, but I can't relate it's display based on it.

so far I have this:

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  jwtHelper: JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();
  public location = '';

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private http: Http) {
    this.location = router.url;
    this.router.events.subscribe((location) => {
      console.log(location);
      return true;
    });
  }
}
```

For my app component.ts

```html
<div class="app-nav">
  <!-- style="display:none; -->
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
</div>
<div class="container outlet">

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</div>
```

and html

the `<app-nav></app-nav>` selector must not appear only when the URL is empty, which is the `'/'` route, but must be available in every other route. Can someone help me?

Comment: use conditional rendering on it

Comment: sorry i'm quite a noob to angular and js, could you provide me some 'how to' please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you could basically leverage the power of rxjs here.
`this.router.events` is a stream of events (known as Observable).
We can take the stream and convert it (`map`) to a boolean property.
Then we set an `*ngIf` on a component that we want to toggle, as follows:

```
<app-nav *ngIf="showNav$ | async"></app-nav>
```

Since `this.router.events` is a stream, every time it emits a new value, a new boolean will be generated. The stream used in the html template used together with the `async` pipe, unwraps the boolean value into the html, it also automatically subscribes and unsubscribes for you.

A full working stackblitz is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-hide-nav?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts).

PS. And by the way, do not get discouraged by someone downvoting your questions, it happens more and more often here, without explanation why. **I upvoted your question back, because it makes a perfect sense and answers can be helpful to others.**

Comment: It actually helped me A LOT, thanks for the support man! It now appears only on one route, how can I make it reverse, make sure it doesn't apperas ONLY on that route?

Comment: I'm also getting an error, 
`ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(23,26): error TS2339: Property 'url' does not exist on type 'RouterEvent | RouteConfigLoadStart | ChildActivationStart'.
  Property 'url' does not exist on type 'RouteConfigLoadStart'.`

Does it break anything?

Comment: Ok so, regarding the first one: just adjust the condition in app.component - I used `.endsWith('/path2')` just as an example. Second one: I think you have to actually use `event['url']` notation or cast event to NavigationEnd: `(event as NavigationEnd)`

Comment: I can't figure out the problem with ´map(event => event.url.endsWith('path2'))´. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Conditional Rendering

```
<Component *ngIf="iWant ? true : false" />
```

It looks something like this.

check this [docs](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/v/v2.3/handout/directives/ng_if_directive.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
<h2 *ngIf="route.url === '/'"> {{title}} </h2>
```

or

```
<h2 *ngIf="route.url !== '/'"> {{title}} </h2>
```

or

```
<h2 *ngIf="route.url === '/books'"> {{title}} </h2>
```

In the component inject the object Router in the constructor

```
  constructor (public route: Router) {}
```